# How can I use session_destroy() in a button without automatic log out?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I need to use Logout functionality in my app. I choose a different method than suggested in almost every article about session_destroy. I'm not using separate logout.php file to call session_destroy(), but rather want to either use it as below,

`<li><a href="<?php session_destroy(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>`

or call a function in my functions.php file like below,

`<li><a href="<?php userLogout(); ?>"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>`

function for logout,
`function userLogout(){session_destroy();}`

but when I try to use either one, I'm getting automatically redirected to login page, when I refresh the page or try to goto another page.

how can I fix this?

Comment: You must redirect the user to a page that executes the `session_destroy()` code via PHP. There is NO OTHER alternative.. good luck <3

Comment: @zanderwar can't I do it inside href?

Comment: No, with your code above, you've already destroyed the session even without the user clicking on it

Comment: You can't use client side functionality to execute something that only server side has access to, otherwise users could destroy your website in a single yawn

Comment: @zanderwar can I use my functions.php file somehow then? without having separate file for just logout

Comment: "I choose a different method than ````suggested in almost every article about session_destroy````" <-- ins't this a clue?

Comment: I went with jquery+ajax. thank you everyone who helped me